# How to automatically remove markers depending on Boolean value in JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Milan",
    "availability": true,
    "lat": 45.4655,
    "long": 9.1865,
    "marker": "example.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Berlin",
    "availability": true,
    "lat": 52.520008,
    "long": 13.404954,
    "marker": "example.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "city": "Paris",
    "availability": false,
    "lat": 48.864716,
    "long": 2.349014
  }
]
```

What happens so far is if a city has `"availability": true` then the `"marker"` within the JSON file appears on my map. However the other city's that have `"availability": false` are showing the Google Maps red marker on my map when I don't want any marker to show if the `"availability": false`.

This is my code so far:

```
var map;
function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.520008, 13.404954),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoom: 2
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

$.getJSON('example.com', function(data) { 
            $.each(data, function(i, value) {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.long);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                icon: value.marker,
                map: map
               });
          });
     });
}
```

Any help on how to remove these Google Maps Red Markers on a city with `"availability": false` would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the value in the loop, also you don't need a variable assigned the marker, it get's lost in the loop anyways.

```
$.getJSON('example.com', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
        // Don't create a marker if field is false
        if (value.availability === false) {
            return;
        }

        // No variables used
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.long),
            icon: value.marker,
            map: map
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtered = data.filter(item => item.availability);
$.each(filtered, function(i, value) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    icon: value.marker,
    map: map
  });
 });
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but it's not as efficient as adding an `if` statement to the original loop, since this adds a second loop.

Comment: It's a valid solution but not a good answer without comment and explanation.